# referencing a column in a Google sheets array literal

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-arrayformula, google-sheets-arrays, google-sheets-filter

Is there a way to refer to columns in a literal array like so:

```
=FILTER({lengthy_arrayformula_1, lengthy_arrayformula_2}, condition referencing column 2 of the array literal in previous argument)
```

or

```
=INDEX({lengthy_arrayformula_1, lengthy_arrayformula_2}, row, 2nd col of the literal array)
```

**without** creating 'buffer columns' that hold intermediate results.

Comment: Welcome to [Web Applications Stack Exchange](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/tour). Consider sharing a publicly editable [sample spreadsheet](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/138383/269219) with realistic-looking data, and showing your _hand-entered_ expected results there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try [`query()`](https://support.google.com/drive/answer/3093343), like this:

```
=arrayformula( 
  query( 
    { to_pure_number(Sheet1!A2:F), regexreplace(trim(Sheet2:A2:A)), "a", "b") },
    "where Col2 < 42", 
    0 
  ) 
)
```

See the [`query()`](https://support.google.com/drive/answer/3093343) help page for more info.

Comment: I tinkered with QUERY a bit. I am somewhat familiar with the syntax, but I don't get the idea behind the data array in your answer. Could you break it down and explain the role of TO_PURE_NUMBER and REGEXREPLACE here? And why is the query wrapped in ARRAYFORMULA?

Comment: Although I have marked this is the answer, I am not yet quite sure it does what I want. I wish to extract that column and manipulate it for example as an input to a formula. column identifiers like Col1 or Col2 can only be used inside the WHERE clause of the query statement. Is there a way to use them as input to other formulas, like for example perform a VLOOKUP on them?

Comment: Consider sharing a publicly editable [sample spreadsheet](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/138383/269219) with realistic-looking data, and showing your _hand-entered_ expected results there.